# how is the code for showing the random image on the screen?

Tags: iphone, ios5

Hi all, I have implemented code like shown below. When I click on the pressdeal button, the image is not appearing on the screen. What do I need to do to make the image appear on the UIImageView?

```
- (void)viewDidload{
    imagesarray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"bg1.png",@"bg2.png",@"back-button.png",@"bluestar.png",nil];

    imageOut = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
}

-(IBAction)pressDeal{
    index=arc4random()%4;
    image=[UIImage imageNamed:[imagesarray objectAtIndex:index]];
    NSLog(@"**********2222************%@",imageOut);
    [imageOut setImage:image];
    NSLog(@"***********333***********%@",imageOut);
}




2012-03-20 16:41:34.135 pocker[1552:f803] **********2222************<UIImageView: 0x6a71000; frame = (0 0; 0 0); userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x6a73450>>
2012-03-20 16:41:34.179 pocker[1552:f803] ***********333***********<UIImageView: 0x6a71000; frame = (0 0; 0 0); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x6a73450>>
```

Comment: You want "viewDidLoad" not "viewDidload" - that mistake certainly won't help you (assuming this is your actual code, not just a rewrite)

Comment: - (void)viewDidLoad {
 imagesarray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"bg1.png",@"bg2.png",@"back-button.png",@"bluestar.png",nil];
 
 imageOut = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
 [super viewDidLoad];
    

 }

Comment: (Also you're likely to have a number of memory leaks, but these are orthogonal to your main issue)

Comment: i have done it in viewdidload method although same problem occurring

Comment: Case is important - not `viewDidload`, nor `viewdidload`, but `viewDidLoad`

Comment: As I said in your previous question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9734415/how-to-display-the-five-images-randomly-out-of-52-images) I would suggest you take a step back and learn the BASICS of programming and in particular the iOS SDK. You are trying to run before you can walk.

Answer (score 0):

You are not adding the image view to the screen. Somehwere add this

```
[self.view addSubView:imageOut];
```

You will also need to set the frame of the `imageOut` view. something like

```
imageOut.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,460);
```